# 'push' new number into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a long list of dates stored in a CSV file. I have managed to load this dataset successfully using d3.js. Now I want to add another column to this dataset containing a random number for each date in my list.

I believe this dataset has been loaded as an array of objects. So I am using the code below to try and iterate through the array. I think the `push` method is the wrong way to do it, though, as this involves objects.

```
d3.csv('claims_cwy.csv', rowConverter, function(dataset) {
    console.log(dataset);

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {           
        var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        dataset[i].push(newNumber);
    }
```

[image: my dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a random number to each object in the array this is the way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           
    var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    dataset[i]['random_number'] = newNumber;
}
```

This will create a new property called `random_number` for each object

Answer (score 3):

Despite this question having several answers, none of them deals with the idiomatic D3:

Since you already have a [row conversion function](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv), use that function to change the objects in the data array. Just add this to the row function (using `d` as the first parameter):

```
d.random = Math.random() * 10;
//  ^----- or any other property name
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar,baz
12,34,21
14,42,27
17,35,17`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, rowConverter);

function rowConverter(d) {
  d.random = Math.random() * 10;
  return d;
}

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally! You might also want to keep the `columns` field in sync with the objects, i.e. `const FIELD = "random"; function rowConverter(d, i, columns) { if (i===0) columns.push(FIELD); d[FIELD] = Math.random() * 10; }`. Or, if this seems akward, you could do it in the main callback instead.

Comment: Good tip. Since most users don't even know that the `columns` property exists I didn't thought about adding that new value to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
d3.csv('claims_cwy.csv', rowConverter, function(dataset) {
    console.log(dataset);

    for(var i=0; i<dataset.length; i++) {           
        var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        dataset[i].nameOfProperty = newNumber;
    }
}
```

You get each object from the array and give it a new property with the random number in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nice and neatly with the array map() method. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
>   array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

So for each element in your dataset array you return the original properties and also add the new random_number property.

See the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanwadd/hqnvecr5/)

```
var dataset = [
    {"date": "02/10/2017", "climb": "696"},
    {"date": "04/10/2017", "climb": "1004"},
    {"date": "06/10/2017", "climb": "1516"},
    {"date": "13/10/2017", "climb": "932"},
    {"date": "15/10/2017", "climb": "2005"}
];

dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
  return {
      "date": d.date,
      "climb": d.climb,
      "random_number": Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
  }
});
```

It's worth mentioning, as you're using d3, that you could use one of the various random number methods in the [d3-random module](https://github.com/d3/d3-random) instead of Math.random().